# Getting ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE with Codeigniter and PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to generate a simple excel file using PhpSpreadsheet and Codeigniter on my localhost environment (XAMPP and Mac).

First, I put PhpSpreadsheet on my project using composer: 
**composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet**

After that, I edit the config.php file: **$config['composer_autoload'] = 'vendor/autoload.php';**

And this is the code that I'm testing inside my main controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

class Gestao extends CI_Controller {

    public function excel()
    {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

        $filename = 'name-of-the-generated-file';

        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'. $filename .'.xlsx"'); 
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $writer->save('php://output'); // download file 
}
}
```

When I call the controller and the excel on the browser (Chrome), I get the message:

**This site can’t be reached.**

**ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE**

I remember that when I tried to use PHPExcel I had the same problem inside Codeigniter. Am I missing something?

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295549/phpspreadsheet-working-on-local-but-not-on-live

Comment: Hum.. I think php_gd2, php_xml and php_zip are all enabled.